# como puedo hacer una validación de un attributo de un elemento?

Tags: javascript, html

Si está el li con class="";

```
<li id="li_1" class=""><a style="background-color: #D8FFF9;" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" id="div_1" aria-expanded="false">Columna 1</a></li>
```

Columna 1

Si está li con class="active"

```
<li id="li_1" class="active"><a style="background-color: #D8FFF9;" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" id="div_1" aria-expanded="true">Columna 1</a></li>
```

Columna 1

Me gustaria hacer una validacion segun si esta "" o active pero no se de que forma me lo puede reconocer así no me funciona:

```
if (($("#li_1").attr("class") == "") && ($("#li_2").attr("class") == "")) {

    alert("Advertencia: Primero debes seleccionar una columna.");






} else {
  //que siga
}
```

necesito que si uno de los dos no está activo que haga la edvertencia si hay uno de los activo que siga

Comment: Por que no te funciona? yo acabo de probar y funciona perfectamente

Comment: ¿Esa condición la tienes embedida en tu misma página donde están tus li, o está en un archivo externo? ¿Si estás descargando jQuery correctamente? ¿En qué momento se ejecuta tu condición, durante un evento o al cargar la página?

Answer (score 0):

puede que no te funcione por la versión de jquery, prueba usando prop en vez de attr

```
if ($("#li_1").prop("class") == "") {

        alert("Advertencia: Primero debes seleccionar una columna.");


    } else {




    }
```

Comment: Dudo mucho que por ahí vaya el problema, si tiene una versión antigua >= 1.0 de jQuery, `attr()`funcionaría antes que `prop()` porque la segunda fue agregada en versiones posteriores (1.6)

Comment: ya está solucionado el problema era cambiar el || por &&

Answer (score 0):

Tu ejemplo debería funcionar. Asegúrate de que jQuery se está cargando correctamente y de que no estás ejecutando el código antes de crearse los elementos de la página.

```js
$(function(){
  if ($("#li_1").attr("class") == "") {
    alert("Advertencia: Primero debes seleccionar una columna. (1)");
  } else {
  }
  if ($("#li_2").attr("class") == "") {
    alert("Advertencia: Primero debes seleccionar una columna. (2)");
  } else {
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="li_1" class=""><a style="background-color: #D8FFF9;" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" id="div_1" aria-expanded="false">Columna 1</a></li>
<li id="li_2" class="active"><a style="background-color: #D8FFF9;" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" id="div_2" aria-expanded="false">Columna 2</a></li>
```

Por otra parte para comprobar las clases incluidas en un elemento dispones en jQuery del método hasClass:

```js
$(function(){
  if ($("#li_1").hasClass("active")) {
  }
  else{
    alert("Advertencia: Primero debes seleccionar una columna. (1)");
  }

  if ($("#li_2").hasClass("active")) {
  }
  else{
    alert("Advertencia: Primero debes seleccionar una columna. (2)");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="li_1" class=""><a style="background-color: #D8FFF9;" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" id="div_1" aria-expanded="true">Columna 1</a></li>
<li id="li_2" class="active"><a style="background-color: #D8FFF9;" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" id="div_2" aria-expanded="true">Columna 2</a></li>
```

Par comprobar que algún elemento tenga la clase `active` lo mejor que puedes hacer es utilizar un selector de jQuery que te coja los elementos `li` que tengan la clase `active` y comprobar si te devuelve algún elemento.

Mira este ejemplo. He cambiado los estilos de los elementos activos (rojo) y no activos (azul) para que se vea más claro.
Al pulsar sobre cualquier elemento se activa/desactiva.

Al pulsar el botón comprueba si hay elementos de la lista con la clase active. Si hay elementos saca un mensaje indicando cuantos y si no saca el mensaje de advertencia:

```js
$(function(){
  // Al hacer click sobre un elemento li 'alterna' la clase active
  // Si la tiene la quita y si no se la pone
  $('#listacolumnas li').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
  
  // Al pulsar el botón 'Comprobar' se comprueba si alguna está activa
  $('#BtnComprobar').click(function(){
    var activos = $('#listacolumnas li.active');
    if (activos.length){
      alert('Hay ' + activos.length + ' elementos activos');
    }
    else{
      alert("Advertencia: Primero debes seleccionar una columna.");
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#listacolumnas li a{
  background-color: #D8FFF9;
  color: blue;
}
#listacolumnas li.active a{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="listacolumnas">
  <li id="li_1"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home" id="div_1" aria-expanded="false">Columna 1</a></li>
  <li id="li_2"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home" id="div_2" aria-expanded="false">Columna 2</a></li>
  <li id="li_3"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home" id="div_3" aria-expanded="false">Columna 3</a></li>
  <li id="li_4"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home" id="div_4" aria-expanded="false">Columna 4</a></li>
  <li id="li_5"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home" id="div_5" aria-expanded="false">Columna 5</a></li>
  <li id="li_6"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home" id="div_6" aria-expanded="false">Columna 6</a></li>  
</ul>
<button id="BtnComprobar">Comprobar</button>
```

Comment: La solución del OP funciona, habría que ver el motivo por el cual a él no, capaz y no ha descargado jQuery a su página. o que nos de más contexto en cuanto a cómo está mandando llamar ese bloque de código.

Comment: Ok. Tienes razón. Amplio la respuesta para incluir su aproximación funcionando. Aunque para este caso me sigue pareciendo más óptimo utilizar el método hasClass.

Comment: vale chicos creo que el problema es que quiero hacer dos a la vez es decir necesito que los dos li uno de id li_1 y otro de li_2 si alguno de los dos está activo que se pueda

Comment: He ampliado la respuesta para mostrarte este caso. Espero que te sirva